# Probit regression in Python

Tags: python, regression

I am trying to implement Probit regression. Dependent values are credit which has integer values 0 and 1. The other three features are salaries, sales, and stores. Before I put in the model I scaled these three features with a Robust Scaler. Below you can see the result of the regression

```
import statsmodels.api as smf
probit_model=smf.Probit(y,X)
result=probit_model.fit_regularized ()
print(result.summary2())
```

[image]

The final output of this regression you can see above. But I am badly surprised that other values are NaN expect coefficients.

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: @Koedlt Do you have something concrete related to the question?